# How use a ViewModel & LiveData observer in multiple Activity?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, kotlin, android-jetpack

I developed an App by MVVM pattern and google jetpack dependencies.
I have a `SampleViewModel` that has a method that I need it observer.
I have two View called `FActivity` and `SActivity`, for firstly I created instance `SampleViewModel` in `FActivity` and subscribe observer to LiveData by ViewModel:

```
class FActivity : Acivity{
   onCreate(){
      val vm = ViewModelsProviders
              .of(this)
              .get(SampleViewModel::class.java)

         vm.liveData.observe(this, Observer { basic ->
                Log.i("TAG", "Yes I received from SActivity");
         });)
   }
}
```

now, I will do operation `enqueue()` method in `SActivity` and observer to `FActivity`

```
class SActivity : Acivity{
   onCreate(){
      val vm = ViewModelsProviders
              .of(this)
              .get(SampleViewModel::class.java)

         vm.enqueue();
}
```

but I trace operation creating instance `ViewModelProviders` that renew instance ViewModel and no observe to `FActivity`.
Now, I will know best way what is handle?

Comment: It's possible to share same ViewModel objects between Fragments of same activity but not for different activities.

Comment: @JeelVankhede, I see it, But no way for activities?

Answer (score 2):

> But no way for activities?

Correct. In Android Jetpack development, closely-coupled UI screens are supposed to be implemented as fragments, and they might share a common `ViewModel`. You are welcome to have multiple activities, but they should be very loosely coupled with other activities in the app, in cases where there would be no need for a shared `ViewModel` (e.g., the main activity and a "Help" screen activity).